# graph & tree representation

Tags: graph, vector, tree, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

Can anyone tell me how to represent graph using vector through adjacency matrix & list . Also how to represent tree in c & c++ . How to represent graph using adjacency matrix & list in C .

Answer (score 0):

The [Algorithm Design Manual](http://sist.sysu.edu.cn/~isslxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf) has a nice chapter on graphs.

[Classic Data Structures In C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201508893) has a nice chapter on trees.